# How to stop and make sure OOP code is working?

Tags: c#, oop

This is really my first program I've tried using OOP principles.  I don't know how to make all the classes interact with each other quite yet.  I think I've initialized a deck of cards, but I just want to look at one of the card objects and make sure it looks right.  I thought I could do this with a Console.WriteLine(cards[0]), but have no idea where to put this to get it to display.  In the main method?  In the class where I initialized the deck?  If I put it in the main method, it doesn't recognize cards[0], and it won't display anything if I put the WriteLine in the deck class.  Is there a different way to step through and take a look?  Thanks!

Card Class

```
namespace BlackJack
{


        public enum suits {
            Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds
        }

        public enum cardValues {
            Two=2,
            Three=3,
            Four =4,
            Five=5,
            Six=6,
            Seven=7,
            Eight=8,
            Nine=9,
            Ten=10,
            Jack=10,
            Queen=10,
            King=10,
            Ace=11

        }
    public class Card
    {
        public suits suit { get; set; }
        public cardValues cardValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Deck Class

```
namespace BlackJack
{

    public class Deck
    {
        private List<Card> cards;

        public Deck()
        {
            this.newDeck();
        }

        public void newDeck()
        {
            cards = new List<Card>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
                {
                    cards.Add(new Card() { suit = (suits)i, cardValue = (cardValues)j });
                    Console.WriteLine(cards[1]);
                    Console.ReadLine();   
        }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create an instance of Deck class in main method.

Comment: You have cards private so it can't be read from main.  Make public : private List<Card> cards;

Comment: thanks, I caught that right away but it still didn't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay one thing you need to do is overload the ToString() of your Card class so that it knows how to transform it into a string.

Do you classes like this:

```
public class Deck
{
    //This needs to be public on the get side to be visible outside
    //of the Deck object
    public IList<Card> Cards { get; private set; }

    public Deck()
    {
        NewDeck();
    }

    #region Helper Methods

    private void NewDeck()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            //Start your index at 2 since you enum starts at Two = 2
            //just as an FYI it's bad practice to not start an enum
            //without a zero based answer.
            for (var j = 2; j < 13; j++)
            {
                Cards.Add(new Card {Suit = (Suit)i, Value = (CardValue)j } );
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Helper Methods
}

public enum Suit
{
    Spades, 
    Hearts, 
    Clubs, 
    Diamonds
}

public enum CardValue
{
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    King = 10,
    Ace = 11

}
public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public CardValue Value { get; set; }

    //Tell your card class how to turn into a string representation
    public override string ToString()
    {

        return $"{Value} of {Suit}"; //This is C# 6
        //return string.Format("{0} of {1}", Value, Suit); <-- if less than C#6
    }
}
```

Since it looks like you are using a Console app since you are using Console.WriteLine() inside the main you can check all your cards this way while you are testing.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var deck = new Deck();
    foreach (var card in deck.Cards)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
    }
}
```

My final thing is that you are going to have to change how you initialize your deck. Because you have Ten, Jack, Queen, King all equal 10, your cast of `Value = (CardValue)j` won't know which one to pick. But this should be enough to get you unstuck of not seeing the values of your cards while you are figuring this out and you can move forward.

EDIT: ---------------------------------
After using the StackOverflow chat we chatted and figured out how to best initialize his Blackjack Value while not corrupting the basic Card object past it's Suit and Face. Shuffle was also added since the conversation got long. But all OOP has been met.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var deck = new BlackJackDeck();

    deck.Shuffle();

    foreach (var card in deck.Cards)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
    }
}
public class BlackJackDeck
{
    private const int DECKSIZE = 52;
    private Random random;

    //Card is your key, and int is the value of the card
    public IList<BlackJackCard> Cards { get; private set; }


    public BlackJackDeck()
    {
        random = new Random();
        NewDeck();
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        //Documentation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
        for (var i = 0; i < Cards.Count; i++)
        {
            var position = random.Next(i);
            var temp = Cards[i];
            Cards[i] = Cards[position];
            Cards[position] = temp;
        }
    }

    #region Helper Methods

    private void NewDeck()
    {
        Cards = new List<BlackJackCard>(DECKSIZE);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            {
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                    case 11:
                        Cards.Add(new BlackJackCard { Suit = (Suit)i, Face = (CardFace)j, Value = 10});
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        Cards.Add(new BlackJackCard { Suit = (Suit)i, Face = (CardFace)j, Value = 11});
                        break;
                    default:
                        Cards.Add(new BlackJackCard { Suit = (Suit)i, Face = (CardFace)j, Value = (j + 2)});
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Helper Methods
}

public enum Suit
{
    Spades,
    Hearts,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds
}

public enum CardFace
{
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
}

public class BlackJackCard : Card
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //MSDN Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx
        //base.ToString() is the Card classes ToString()
        return $"{base.ToString()} with value: {Value}";
    }
}

//this is for making a basic card and deck of cards
//Inherit from this to create cards specific to different game rules, i.e BlackJack, Go Fish, etc
//Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf(v=vs.71).aspx
public abstract class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public CardFace Face { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Face} of {Suit}";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not his problem, did look at the iteration? `Console.WriteLine(cards[1]);`.

Comment: thanks, good to know.  I've capitalized everything, but it isn't liking my ToString return line.  It is telling me CardValue and Suit are types, which are not valid in the current context.

Comment: Yeah I am working on it. You have a bunch of different issues going on. I will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @ScottVMeyers I updated the answer and in my LinqPad get it to display all the string versions of the card values.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!  I thought I might run into problems with the enum.  I don't know how to fix it though.  How do I give the queen a value of 12 but still make it worth 10 in blackjack?  Also, what is an IList?

Comment: Are you trying to keep track of deck Number versus game value number? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: By the way what school and class is this for? I have seen SO flooded with CardDeck coding questions?

Comment: Oh man, now I've got a bunch of stuff to research.  He's going to ask me why I used IList, what I did with the getters and setters, why I made the newDeck method private.  I guess it is all stuff I need to know.

Comment: hahahahha it's for a coding bootcamp called CoderCamps.  you mean you aren't loving the CardDeck questions!?!?  Last question.  Next I implement the shuffle.  I'm added a third property to card called shuffleIndex.  I want to randomize this number and then sort my deck based off this number.  Do you think I should do this in my initialize function, or afterwards?  Earlier, you said I would run into problems since my face cards are all valued at 10.  I'll cross that bridge later.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a little change in your code:

```
public class Card
{
    public suits suit { get; set; }
    public cardValues cardValue { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Suit: {0}, Value: {1}", this.suit, this.cardValue);
    }
}

//in newDeck():

var card = new Card() { suit = (suits)i, cardValue = (cardValues)j };
Console.WriteLine(card);  //this is where you have a bug
cards.Add(card);
Console.ReadLine()
```

You were always referencing the same card in the list - `Console.WriteLine(cards[1]);`, that's why it didn't work. You were trying to reference cards[1], even before you inserted any any card to index 1.

Comment: I see cards.Add before the Console.WriteLine, so there would be one there.

Comment: Yes, there would be one in cards[0]. That's a pretty trivial bug.

Comment: Turn I missed that it was Index one. But still in his text above the code he is calling out that he thought he could do cards[0], which means I assume he tried that. But becasue ToString() is not over ridden he is not seeing values, which is causing the confusion.

Comment: I am reevaluating the whole thing as we speak.